# Rscript - long time of execution

Tags: r, r-caret, rscript

I'm trying to create predictive model in caret package in R and invoke prediction for new data from terminal/cmd. Here is reproducible example:

```
# Sonar_training.R
  ## learning and saving model
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
set.seed(107)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = Sonar$Class, p = .75,list = FALSE)
training <- Sonar[ inTrain,]
testing  <- Sonar[-inTrain,]
saveRDS(testing,"test.rds")
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                 repeats = 3)
plsFit <- train(Class ~ .,data = training,method = "pls",
            tuneLength = 15,
            trControl = ctrl,
            preProc = c("center", "scale"))

plsClasses <- predict(plsFit, newdata = testing)

saveRDS(plsFit,"fit.rds")
```

And here is script to invoke by Rscript.exe:

```
# script.R
  ##reading model and predict test data
t <- Sys.time()
pls <- readRDS("fit.rds")
testing <- readRDS("test.rds")
head(predict(pls, newdata = testing))
print(Sys.time() - t)
```

I run this in terminal with following statement:

```
pawel@pawel-MS-1753:~$ Rscript script.R
Loading required package: pls

Attaching package: ‘pls’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

loadings

[1] M M R M R R
Levels: M R
Time difference of 2.209697 secs
```

Is there any way to do it faster/more efficient? For example is there possibility to not loading packages every execution? Is *readRDS* correct for reading models in this case?

Comment: Profile your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to profile your code with the "profvis" package:

```
#library(profvis)
profvis({    

   for (i in 1:100){
    #your code here
    }

})
```

I tried and it happens that 99% of the execution time is training time, 1% is saving/loading RDS data, and the rest costs about 0 (loading packages, loading data,...):

[image]

So if you don't want to optimize the training function itself, it seems you have very few ways to reduce execution time.

Comment: Time of training function is not of big importance here.  Once I learned model I use this only in *readRDS* function. I care only about time of execution script.R in console. But thank you for profvis package now I see that 1.5 of 2.2 sec is reading model.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this occur for PLS classification models and I'm not sure of the issue. However, try using `method = "simpls"` instead. You will get approximately the same answers and it should complete quickly.